# how to get the duration time of object tag in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to find time duration of only mp4 type video and length of video.

I have used video tag I got there these values but it won't support mp4 file I tried a lot but fail to play only mp4 file in video tag. It supports only .ogg files.

If possible to play mp4 in video then also it will be grat for me.

```
  <OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" id="om1"  WIDTH="500"HEIGHT="400" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0">
  <PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="demo.mp4">
  <PARAM name="AUTOPLAY" VALUE="false">
  <PARAM name="CONTROLLER" VALUE="true">
  <EMBED SRC="demo.mp4" WIDTH="500" HEIGHT="400" id="om" AUTOPLAY="false"   CONTROLLER="true" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" >
  </EMBED>
  </OBJECT>
```

Comment: Mp4 playback is only capable of playback in certain browsers

Comment: You will need additional plugins to play mp4. It is supported in chrome though.

Comment: There is good resource for it http://caniuse.com/#feat=mpeg4 It has slightly outdated Opera column, but you can get general info.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using HTML5 video element , you can get by the use of "duration" property which will return in sec.

like this [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-duration)

Otherwise, you may need to get the required information from server side

Answer (score 0):

`<OBJECT>` tags do not have a duration, as their content is not guaranteed to have any relation to time at all — for instance, a 3D model or a PDF would not have a duration.

If you are using a Flash video player, the player may have methods to retrieve the length of the video. How this works will depend entirely on the player you are using. However, your example is missing some required parameters (specifically, `<param name="movie">` for the SWF file), so it will not do anything at all.